# DataTables - click function is triggered once on first click, twice on second, three on third, etc

Tags: jquery, datatables

Each time I click on the "#archivedHidden" button the number of times the function to toggle column visibility is triggered is increased by one. This means that on the first click the archived date column is shown (starts as hidden), second click the column is not hidden (should be), third click the column is hidden (should not be), fourth click the column remains hidden (should be).

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#includedContent").load("Menu.html");

    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();

    $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').text('');
    $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse2').text('');

    $("#showAccountUpdateForm").hide();
    sessionStorage.setItem('ssArchived', "Hidden");
//  alert(sessionStorage.getItem('ssArchived'));

    $("#datepicker1").datepicker({
      showOn: "both",
      format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    });

    jQuery.validator.addMethod(
        "regex",
        function(value, element, regexp) {
            if (regexp.constructor != RegExp)
                regexp = new RegExp(regexp);
            else if (regexp.global)
                regexp.lastIndex = 0;
            return this.optional(element) || regexp.test(value);
        },
        "Please enter correct Characters."
    );


    //Display the Accounts
    $('#archivedHidden').click(function(){     

        if($(this).text().trim() == 'Archived Hidden' ){
            $(this).text('Archived Shown');
            sessionStorage.setItem('ssArchived', "Shown");
//          alert(sessionStorage.getItem('ssArchived'));

            showDataTable();

        }else{
             $(this).text('Archived Hidden');
             sessionStorage.setItem('ssArchived', "Hidden");
//           alert(sessionStorage.getItem('ssArchived'));

             showDataTable();
        }
    });

    showDataTable();

    //Validate form showAccountUpdateForm
    $("#showAccountUpdateForm").validate({
        //debug: true,

        rules: {
            password: {
                required: true,
                regex: /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]{8,}/,
                minlength: 8
            },
        },

        messages: {
            enterPassword1: {
                regex: "Please enter at least 8 characters containing at least 1 lower case, 1 upercase, 1 special and 1 numeric.",
                minlength: "Your password must consist of at least 8 characters.",
            },
        },

        submitHandler : function(showAccountUpdateForm) {
            //do something here
            //var frm = $('#contactForm');
            //alert($("#accountName").val());

            $.ajax({
                url : 'AccountUpdateView', // Your Servlet mapping or JSP(not suggested)
                data : {
                    ssAccountLevel : sessionStorage.getItem('ssAccountLevel'),
                    ssResAccountID : sessionStorage.getItem('ssResAccountID'),
                    password : $("#password").val(),   
                }, 
                type : 'POST',
                dataType : 'html' // Returns HTML as plain text; included script tags are evaluated when inserted in the DOM. 
            })
            .fail (function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                //alert(jqXHR.responseText);
                $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').text('Error updating Account.');
            })
            .done(function(responseJson){
                $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').text('Account updated.');
            })
        }
    });
}); // end document.ready

function showDataTable() {
    //Show DataTable
    if ( $.fn.dataTable.isDataTable( '#accountUpdateTable' ) ) {
        var accountUpdateTable = $('#accountUpdateTable').DataTable();

      //Toggle the "Archived" column
        $('#archivedHidden').on( 'click', function (e) {
            alert("Toggle column");
            e.preventDefault();

            // Get the column API object
            var column = accountUpdateTable.column(6);

            // Toggle the visibility
            column.visible( ! column.visible() );
        } );
    }
    else {
        var accountUpdateTable = $('#accountUpdateTable').DataTable( {

            "info":     false,
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: ['copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'],
            columns: [
                  {data: 'accountId',
                      visible: false,
                      searchable: false},
                  {data: 'emailaddress'},
                  {data: 'surname',
                      defaultContent: ""},
                  {data: 'otherNames',
                      defaultContent: ""},
                  {data: 'level',
                      defaultContent: ""},
                  {data: 'enabled',
                      defaultContent: ""},
                  {data: 'archived',
                      visible: false,
                      defaultContent: ""},
                  {data: null,
                      className: "center",
                      defaultContent: '<button id="reset">Reset</button>'
                  }
                 ],
             columnDefs: [ {
                 targets: [6],
                 render: $.fn.dataTable.render.moment( 'DD/MM/YYYY' )
             } ],
        } );

        //Toggle the "Archived" column
        $('#archivedHidden').on( 'click', function (e) {
            alert("Toggle column");
            e.preventDefault();

            // Get the column API object
            var column = accountUpdateTable.column(6);

            // Toggle the visibility
            column.visible( ! column.visible() );
        } );
    }


    //Get Account List
    $.ajax({
        url : 'AccountsListView', // Your Servlet mapping or JSP(not suggested)
        data : {
            ssAccountLevel : sessionStorage.getItem('ssAccountLevel'),
            ssAccountID : sessionStorage.getItem('ssAccountID'),
            ssArchived : sessionStorage.getItem('ssArchived'),
        },
        type : 'POST',
    })
    .fail (function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
//      alert(jqXHR.responseText);
        if(jqXHR.responseText.includes('No Accounts')){
            $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse3').text('No Accounts.');
        }else{
            $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse3').text('Error getting Accounts.');
        }
        accountUpdateTable.clear().draw();
    })
    .done(function(responseJson1a){
        // JSON response to populate the activities table
        dataType: "json";

//      alert(JSON.stringify(responseJson1a));
//      Result of alert is:
//          [{"adId":"2","grpId":"2","adActivityID":"2","adActivityName":"Visit Ryde Fire Station","adStartDate":"2017-05-24","adEndDate":"2017-05-24"}]
        accountUpdateTable.clear();
        accountUpdateTable.rows.add(responseJson1a).draw();
    })

    $('#accountUpdateTable tbody').on( 'click', '#reset', function () {
//      alert("Reset");
        var data = accountUpdateTable.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();

        sessionStorage.setItem('ssResAccountID', data.accountId);
        $("#account").val(data.emailaddress);
        $("#password").val("");

        $("#showAccountUpdateForm").show();

    } );
}
```

Comment: Well you have several click handlers on `#archivedHidden`, and some of them are defined after you clicked it (in `showDataTable`). Why do you need to define that many handlers for the same event on the same element? Whenever possible, event handlers should be kept out of functions.

Comment: Yes, it was the "showDataTable()" causing the error. I have also combined the two click handlers and moved to after the "if ( $.fn.dataTable.isDataTable( '#accountUpdateTable' ) ) {}else{}". Unfortunately still in the function as the DataTable part needs it there.